# python "Name error: name 'a' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I dont kow why I keep getting this issue of "Name Error: Name 'a' is not defined"

```
def addition():

 a = input("Enter your first number: ")

b = input("Enter secondary number: ")

c = int(a) + int (b)

print(a," + ",b," = ",c," . ")
```

Comment: Your code is improperly indented. Add a space to the start of every line after `a=input...`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you've indented it, but I've got it to work like this...

```
def addition():

   a = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
   b = int(input("Enter secondary number: "))
   c = a + b
   print(a," + ",b," = ",c," . ")

addition()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, I don't know what was wrong with my indention.

Comment: @GageS You don't know what was wrong with it? How so?

Comment: I'm very new to python I'm just starting to program